# How to read a CSV file from Azure File share into a memory stream using C#?

Tags: c#, azure, file-storage

I'm working on a requirement where I need to read CSV files from Azure File Share location(Not Azure blob) using C# console application. I've got to a point where I'm able to read the file as seen in the below code.

But how can I get the file content into a memory stream?

```
// List all files/directories under the root directory
IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference()
                                               .ListFilesAndDirectories();

            if (fileList != null)
            {
                foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
                {
                    if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Retrieved File: " + listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
                        WriteToLog("Retrieved File: " + listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());

                        _filename = listItem.Uri.Segments.Last();//Gets the CSV file name
                   }
                }
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe your issue in detail and provide the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to download the file to stream using the below code. Hope this is helpful to someone trying to achieve this with a CSV input file.

CloudFile file = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference(_blobfilename);

```
                    long? offset = Convert.ToInt64(file.Properties.Length * 0);
                    long? length = Convert.ToInt64(file.Properties.Length * -100);

                    file.DownloadRangeToStream(ms, null, null);
```